# How to run MD5 check for multiple fastq files in different subdirectories?

Tags: genome, sequence-analysis, illumina

I have received Illumina sequencing reads for 100 samples. I have 8 `R1.fastq.gz` and 8 `R2.fastq.gz` files for each sample in each subfolder. I want to run an `MD5` check for all the `fastq` files in each subfolder.

My folder structure looks like:

```
/mydata/sequencing/clean
/mydata/sequencing/clean/Sample1
/mydata/sequencing/clean/Sample2
......
/mydata/sequencing/clean/Sample100
```

I am using the following code being on the `/mydata/sequencing/clean` directory.

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum-lite {} \;
```

This code is printing the md5 result on Terminal.

How do I get these results printed to a `.txt` file? Besides, is there a more elegant way to do this MD5 check?

Thank you.

Comment: You posted the same thing in Biostars.org :) https://www.biostars.org/p/9509386/

Comment: Haha yes. Because sometimes I do not get a reply to my questions (may be they are  too naive some times) :(

Comment: Glad you got the answer.

Comment: thats because its on the wrong stack

Comment: Anyways it is always great to receive feedback on bioinformatics problems. Nice to see that many roads lead to Rome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small modification,

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum-lite {} \; >> output.txt
```

If you use `>` the output will almost certainly contain a single record.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Is there any other code that you know of for looping the md5 command over different subfolders?

Comment: Yes of course ... there are loads of ways to do this. A bash script is good (separate question IMO). However, the > and >> will still be central. In terms of elegance, your one liner looks cool. BTW >> is very likely the solution because of the find approach. One liners are cool BTW.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Your welcome. Your  second question (alternative code) is worth asking because of the variety of ways it can answered, e.g. a bash for loop, Python subprocessing, Perl one liner are the  approaches I can think of.

Comment: Yeah. totally agreed.